# Problems making an histogram with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram with this dataframe. The main issue with this code is that I didn't manage to get a histogram: it looks more like a column graph. How could I fix my code to obtain a histogram?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

midf <- data.frame("x" = c(rep(1975,1), rep(1985,6), rep(1995,17), rep(2005,24), rep(2015,1)))
g1 <- ggplot(midf)
g1 <- g1 + aes ( x = x)
g1 <- g1 + geom_histogram () + geom_histogram(bins=5, position = 'identity', alpha = 0.8)
g1 <- g1 + xlab ("Años de Antiguedad")
g1 <- g1 + ylab ("Cantidad de Objetos")
g1 <- g1 + ggtitle ("Trabajo de Aplicación", subtitle = "Antiguedad de Objetos Encontrados en Océano")
g1 <- g1 + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-2,26), xlim=c(1970,2020))
g1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tidied up the code a bit - you had a redundant `geom_histogram()` in there, and all the label definitions can be in one `labs()` function.

This does produce a histogram - what's different from your expectation?  Do you want to have one bar for each year?  If so, `bins=5` could change to 50 as you've set a 50-year range with your `xlim`.

Overall a histogram is not typically a good way to display discrete data like this - can you give us an idea what you want to show with your plot?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

midf <- data.frame("x" = c(rep(1975,1), rep(1985,6), rep(1995,17), rep(2005,24), rep(2015,1)))

g1 <- ggplot(midf, aes(x = x)) +
  # geom_histogram () +
  geom_histogram(bins=5, position = 'identity', alpha = 0.8) +
  labs(x = "Años de Antiguedad", 
       y = "Cantidad de Objetos",
       title = "Trabajo de Aplicación", 
       subtitle = "Antiguedad de Objetos Encontrados en Océano") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-2,26), xlim=c(1970,2020))

g1
```

Here's a way of doing it with a barplot:

```
g1 <- ggplot(midf, aes(x = factor(x), y=..count..)) +
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.8, width = 0.8) +
  labs(x = "Años de Antiguedad", 
       y = "Cantidad de Objetos",
       title = "Trabajo de Aplicación", 
       subtitle = "Antiguedad de Objetos Encontrados en Océano")
```

You can amend the `width` in the `geom_bar()` line to balance the thickness of the bars and the spacing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Paul. I would like to show with my plot a kind of "histogram" or sth similar. I guess I should get a narrower space between each column in the graph in order it looks more like an histogram. I know it is a discrete data. How could I do it?

Comment: A histogram does not have space between the columns.  I think you may want to look at using a function to count the incidence of each year, then plot those counts as a bar plot - this will give you more options for how you want it to look.

Comment: I've added an example of a bar plot way of doing it, treating the years as factors so each bar is labelled with the year but they won't be spaced out on a timeline.